# How to stop animation of Image-scaling to reset itself?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I have created a copy of the Button template and added an Image in there. 
Then I created a mouseover state for *=> MouseOver to scale the image by 0.1.
It works. However despite leaving the mouse over the image, the animation resets itself back to initial state as if there was no mouseover still in place.

How can I make it stay there?

The second question is regarding the hardcoded path of Source within my Image. How can I inject it from the top into the style rather than having it hardcoded for one specific image? So that its more generic?

Many Thanks

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="1.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="toolbarImage" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="1.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="toolbarImage" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#D8FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#8CFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#3FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                                <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
                            </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="White" CornerRadius="3">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1">
                                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Image x:Name="toolbarImage" Source="./Images/New.png">
                                <Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform CenterY="24" CenterX="24"/>
                                </Image.RenderTransform>
                            </Image>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**UPDATE:**

Despite having set the autoreverse to false, I still havent sorted out the first issue.

```
<VisualTransition From="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0" To="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="1.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="toolbarImage" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="1.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="toolbarImage" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have uploaded a sample here to demo what I mean. Hover with mouse over the New button:
http://sl.venuscloud.com/

Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your requirement does sound a bit impractical to me i.e. scaling images on mouseover and keeping them scaled forever then onwards??

Although if you insist

1. Being part of a Trigger, the scaling animation will anyways be removed (and scaled back to its original size) if you do not hover the mouse.

So for your requirement to fulfill, you can scale-animate the button in an attached behavior and not in Trigger that starts on main thread when mouseover is true (and make sure you write no reverse logic when its not a mouse over).

```
  <Button myNameSpace:MyAttachedBehavior.BeginScalingAnimation="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

So in your attached behavior storyboard's `AutoReverse` property should be false and the scaling should persist after animation ends.

---

Now for next issue for image source...

You would have to create another Attached Property for `Button` which can be of `ImageSource` type. You can TemplateBind to that attached property in your Style.

e.g.

```
  <Button myNameSpace:MyAttachedBehavior.IconPath=".../xyz.png"/>
```

and in `Style`'s `Template`

```
  <Image Source="{TemplateBinding myNameSpace.MyAttachedBehavior:IconPath}" .../>
```

in case if above `TemplateBinding` does not work try `TemplatedParent` as `RelativeSource` in normal `Binding`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Angel, Thanks for your answer. Sorry I think you have miunderstood me. When I hover the mouse over the button, the Image gets scaled bigger, but WHILE I am still hovering over the icon, surley the up-scaling shall remain in place? But this doesn't happen in my code sample. Once I hover over the button, the image get scaled up and then suddenly it goes down to initial non-scaled size, why?

Comment: Also many Thanks for the second resolution. I hope your solution works with Silverlight 4.0 :)

Comment: @Kave, in that case did u set `AutoReverse` property of your animation `StoryBoard` as `false`? Also the second solution to Image should work as Attached Properties and `TemplateBinding` Or `Binding` with `TemplatedParent` should work in Silverlight 4.0 too.

Comment: Many Thanks Angel, I have updated the question, despite the AutoReverse it still jumps back.  Have I missed anything else? Many Thanks

Comment: I have posted the example in here: http://sl.venuscloud.com/  can you please check to see what I mean when you hover with the mouse over the new?  many Thanks

Comment: I have figured it out. The <VisualStateGroup.Transitions> shall be empty. The custom animations there should be going into the MouseOver state further down. :) Thanks